# How to use a predefined dynamic list in a loop correctly in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

In a playbook, I need to use a loop from a dynamic list, I wrote this construction:

```
dirs:
  - one
  - two
  - three

path_to_some_files:
  - some_path/folder/{{ item }}/*.file
  with_items:
    - '{{ dirs }}'
```

But this is not correct. How would it be more correct to write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to achieve. The wildcard in the path suggests you might want to find the patterns. For example, given the tree

```sh
shell> tree some_path
some_path/
├── one
│   ├── A
│   └── A.file
├── three
│   ├── C
│   └── C.file
└── two
    ├── B
    └── B.file
```

the playbook below

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    dirs:
      - one
      - two
      - three
  tasks:
    - find:
        paths: "some_path/{{ item }}"
        patterns: "*.file"
      register: result
      loop: "{{ dirs }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ result.results|json_query('[].files[].path') }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg:
  - some_path/one/A.file
  - some_path/two/B.file
  - some_path/three/C.file
```

---

As a side note, in the example above the loop is not necessary because the parameter [paths](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html#parameter-paths) of the module *find* can be a list. For example, the tasks below give the same result

```yaml
    - find:
        paths: "{{ dirs }}"
        patterns: "*.file"
      register: result
      vars:
        dirs:
          - some_path/one
          - some_path/two
          - some_path/three
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ result.files|json_query('[].path') }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

static list

```
- name: create directory
  file:
    path: "some_path/folder/{{ item }}/*.file"
    state: directory
  loop:
     - one
     - two
     - three
```

list from a variable

```
- name: create directory
  file:
    path: "some_path/folder/{{ item }}/*.file"
    state: directory
  loop: "{{ somelist }}"
```

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#iterating-over-a-simple-list